# Vlookup to compare two tables

Tags: vlookup

IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Table1,Table2,1,FALSE)),"No","Yes")

I want compare all the columns for two tables within a single excel sheet and I used the above formula but somehow the formula always gives "Yes" irrespective of whether the values match or not. Can someone please help me out to get correct comparison results.'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please see the snapshot below

[image]

Formula will be as below. Kindly take this as example and work out as per your wish.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(G1,$A$1:$B$7,2,FALSE)=VLOOKUP(G1,$D$1:$E$7,2,FALSE),"Same","Different")
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why using  cell G1 in your formula?

Comment: I am finding it difficult to understand and also it does not work for me as I may using it wrong